# To disable spaces entering textbox

Tags: mfc

In MFC How to disable spaces entering textbox

Comment: possible duplicate of [MFC control disabling entering spaces in mfc textbox in vc++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426351/mfc-control-disabling-entering-spaces-in-mfc-textbox-in-vc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can update the user entry on OnChangeControl as follows:

```
if ((m_strYOURCONTROL[m_strYOURCONTROL.GetLength() - 1]) == ' ')
{
    m_strYOURCONTROL = m_strYOURCONTROL.Mid(0, m_strYOURCONTROL.GetLength() - 1);
}
```

Comment: how to place cursor at the end of text in mfc.cursor is point to first char if space is entered.

Comment: In this implementation you just check the last entered character.

Comment: what ever character i am entering cursor is moving to starting when i am pressing space.

Comment: UpdateData();
 if ((m_strYOURCONTROL[m_strYOURCONTROL.GetLength() - 1]) == ' ')
{
    m_strYOURCONTROL = m_strYOURCONTROL.Mid(0, m_strYOURCONTROL.GetLength() - 1);
} 
 UpdateData( FALSE );

Answer (score 3):

Just supply the own **OnKeyDown** event handler and filter out the space keys:

```
 void MyEditControl::OnKeyDown(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags) 
 {
   if (nChar == 32)
   {
     // kill the space key down event
     return;
   }

   // let edit control handle the other keys
   CEdit::OnKeyDown(nChar, nRepCnt, nFlags);
 }
```